# Way to break into a javascript function which is looping

Tags: javascript

I expect there's a million answers to this already & I don't know the terminology to phrase the question. But...

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/QD3UK/8/

```
$('body').on('click', '.testDiv', function(){
    console.log($(this))
    repeatTest(1)
})

function repeatTest(n){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.result').append(n+" hi<br />")
        repeatTest(n);
    }, 3000);
    n++
}
```

I want the looping function to start again when the testDiv div is clicked again - so there is only one loop iterating - it doesn't matter what number (n) it starts at.

Please help?
Thanks

Comment: Look for `clearTimeout`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `clearTimeout` to cancel an existing `setTimeout`. So something like:

```
var _handle;

$('body').on('click', '.testDiv', function(){
    clearTimeout(_handle);
    console.log($(this))
    repeatTest(1)
});

function repeatTest(n){
    _handle = window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.result').append(n+" hi<br />")
        repeatTest(n);
    }, 3000);
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Maybe should have made this clear, I'm in a jQuery AJAX loop, which has a timeout option. I'm guessing that the clearTimeout method ain't going to help in this circumstance. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @tozjerimiah You should clarify your question.

Comment: @tozjerimiah Yep, I'm not really sure what you're getting at. `clearTimeout` will kill the existing `setTimeout` so that it won't fire again. If you can provide an example in your question that's a little closer to your actual scenario including the AJAX stuff, that might make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will use your advice when I encounter this scenario. I am going to start a new thread as I've ballsed this one up.